# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.Initializer.asEntityInitializer()" because "initializer" is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-17, hibernate-6.x

I am facing issue with below dependency
groupId = org.hibernate.orm, artifactId = hibernate-core and version = 6.3.1.Final

[image]

I am using, Java 17.0.2 JDK, Spring 6.0.11

This issue was not there up to 6.1.1.FINAL

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.